# using the online mysql server

Tags: mysql

I have thought of developing a web-app needing some database support and do not have a static ip to run servers. Hence i want to know how to use the online database provided by mysql. I have no idea in that matter(except that i know to use mysql).

If somebody can provide some tutorials it will be very helpful

Comment: MySQL provides a hosted service?  This is news to me.  Do you have a link to it?

Comment: It's probably a lot easier to use than an offline MySQL server. :-)

Comment: Leaving aside the mystery hosted service, why do you think you need 'powerful machines' to run the DBMS?

Comment: These are some servers which host mysql (most of them do not have java in their list of scripts though). I don't know how to use them though. http://www.free-webhosts.com/free-mysql-database.php

Comment: @HameesA.Khan: That's Amazon.  They provide hosting for lots of things.  They're one of the largest cloud services available.  Amazon is not "provided by MySQL".

Comment: @David Sorry, sorry, sorry! Let me delete my comment. I thought you asked for any company providing MySQL database hosting. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, neither MySQL nor any other hosting company provide an online hosted mySQL database service. (**Edit**: This is not entirely correct. As @Dan Grossman points out, Amazon offers a hosted database service called [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/#features).)

It would be impractical anyway, as database traffic to a remote server is bound to be very slow. You usually want to run your database on the same server as the web server, or on a neighbouring machine that you are connected to through a fast LAN.

However, running a database server doesn't need to be horribly resource intensive. Chances are you can install mySQL on the same machine your web app runs on.

Comment: Amazon offers an online hosted MySQL database service. It is called Amazon Relational Database Service.

Comment: @Dan didn't know that, thanks. Looks interesting. Edited