# Are there websites to upload a mysql database and connection Java Swing application remotely

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hosting

I have a huge project in **Java Swing** which has its database I created using **MySQL Workbench** on my computer. It's a desktop application so I connect to the database locally through `localhost 127.0.0.1` address. Is it possible to upload the database in some website which accepts execution of sql scripts to create the database, then connect my Java application to it? Are there any websites capable of managing the database on their end and allowing my Java application to connect to it?

I know that it's common and usual in websites where you upload the website folder and the database. But I wonder how it works with desktop application.

I'd like to be able to connect my desktop application to its database to some online service that accepts uploading of database.

So instead of,

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";
```

I can have something like,

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://somewebsiteurltomydb:someport/mydb";
private static final String USERNAME = "someusernameprovidedbyonlineservice";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";
```

I hope my question is clear enough. I just want my database to be uploaded so that if I move the executable desktop application to another PC that has internet connection, then I can simply supply the database `URL`

By the way, my database has hundreds of stored procedures. The services or website I need must support execution of stored procedures.

If such website exists, are there free services? Else, any other alternative ways or place to upload the database?

I'd appreciate any help and suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use google cloud service. see https://cloud.google.com/sql/

also Amazon offers an online hosted MySQL database service. It is called Amazon Relational Database Service. As Dan Grossman said in [using the online mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526115/using-the-online-mysql-server)

unfortunately none of them are free.